# XOR Encryption with a 32 bit int and four char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, bit-manipulation, xor

I'm trying to implement a simple XOR encryption function that takes in an unsigned 32 bit int (big endian), as well as a key in the form of a four letter char array. It then XORs the first eight bits of the int with the first char, then the next eight bits with the next char, etc. Below is what I have although it is outputting 0 as the result of the encryption 8/10 times:

```
unsigned int EncryptXOR(unsigned int x, unsigned char key[]) {
  unsigned int result = 0; // int to hold final result
  unsigned char* ascii; // pointer for chars in key array
  unsigned char* num; // pointer for each 8 bit segment in x
  unsigned int* encryption; // pointer for result
  int i;

  ascii = (unsigned char*)&key;
  num = (unsigned char*)&x;
  encryption = &result;

  for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    *(encryption+i) = ascii[i] ^ num[i]; // for each byte in result, change to XOR of ascii and num
  }
  return result; // return changed result
}
```

My logic with this is the I grab the segments of x (the number to be encrypted) and the chars, XOR them, and then set each segment of the result with this new XORed value. I then return result because the encryption pointer should have updated its values, right? I'm new to C so I may have an obvious logic or coding error that will hopefully be obvious to someone more experienced.

Comment: Whats the problem? What exactly does `it doesn't seem to be working` mean?

Comment: Make `encryption` an `unsigned char *`, and treat it like `ascii` and `num`. Right now, you're using it as an array of `int`, possibly overwriting other data. Also, you should use fixed-size (`stdint.h`) integers instead of `unsigned int` since you're relying on it having a specific size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is with the pointer arithmetic in this line:

```c
*(encryption+i) = ascii[i] ^ num[i];
```

Now, because the `encryption` variable is defined as an `int*`, the addend, `i` will *automatically* be multiplied by `sizeof(int)` by the compiler. That is so that code like the following will work as expected:

```c
int array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int *ptr = &array[0];
*(ptr+2) = 5; // Will actually add "2 * sizeof(int)" to "ptr" - referencing THIRD element of array
```

What you could do is declare `encryption` as a pointer to `unsigned char`:

```c
unsigned char* encryption = (unsigned char*)(&result);
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation; you may also find the **Pointer Arithmetic** section of [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) helpful.

EDIT: A better/safer way to achieve your encryption is to use the bit-shift (`<<`) operator to move the character array elements into the respective bytes of the `result` variable, then `XOR` that (in one fell swoop) with your `x` argument. So, as you have specified *Big-Endian* format, you could use code like this:

```cpp
unsigned int EncryptXOR(unsigned int x, unsigned char key[]) {
  unsigned int mask = (key[0] << 24) | (key[1] << 16) | (key[2] << 8) | key[3];
  return x ^ mask;
}
```

Comment: So the issue is that when I increment the encryption pointer its actually moving 4 bytes of memory instead of 1 byte because its an int?

Comment: @BCool Exactly the point! Make it a `char*` and it then moves only 1 byte.